# TypeScript: Conditional types not working with optional parameters

Tags: typescript

I have a data source, let's call it `getData()`, that returns objects. Sometimes it returns objects of known type (e.g. `Person`, `Animal`), but sometimes the returned object has an unknown shape.

([Link to TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAChBOBnA9gOygXigbyqghgLYQBcUiw8AlqgOYDcU+tpeAroQEYJQC+9AKFCQoAQVRVC+ADaYc5SAGMqERGQrU6fQQID0AKn1QBUIwBUAFlURQawBADN8i6BWTxVTabIDWqZADu6MicAFYQisBQwp4ewGzwqBAAJlCcIFAABizAACL4wPgAFACUmQB0JkYAkgDkhOTA7jS0tlH4Nvjodo7O0DQUEPipyA5ZcEhoUAA+YhJS0plpEfhsiNDVVXgQKdHIje7QwBbQAESKyMkQp1CjTFB+gegxUEUQ5bTlWaeQk6inSwc7nGCBQqCWMRKlVMugEPXgThcUHyhQAwgUILR3BlsCYoL8wWQJmDBFAmPMZGRxJIZIJeAI9IYoAB5BJQZIFfDkZAJJH6WEXVAUKA5FH4ImgqazakLGbkjJYUqYAB8ODxcQS6Gw-DJul0UAAsshFD5dgA3GRsCACfgMhxsVCRKhTNYQMUAHjMUAgAA97KhkjZTSA7mL0fYsfAQMqiooMZGQAB+MhmEpqsmC4UcwpkLoKkUQPKc0qkqAaxLszlMGxe33+wNQB1XBw0XaJ+VQMhh+PYgDaZgAunSGZn2hTZFhXWKiqcujTpKcSoI9WSyQA9KCj8nzqnjkdoYX+YAAaX8QTkU+LS70+tXG63R9PTwlfzlMpkN6gAAlAhAzQgABooGqKAAi6KJjmgfBOGQf89mWLIH2QE8z1QXNUBATIgA))

```
type Person = { name: string; age: number };
type Animal = { species: string };

/** 
 * This interface stores all known object types returned by `getData()`.
 * I'm storing it as an interface instead of `Person | Animal` because I
 * need to store the "code" of a known type (e.g. `"person"` for `Person` type).
 */
interface DataCategory {
  person: Person;
  animal: Animal;
}

/** Our data source */
const getData: Person | Animal | any = () => {
  return {};  // Mocked value
};
```

Now I wish to write a helper function `useData()` to narrow down `getData()`'s return value. It accepts an optional parameter of type `keyof DataCategory` and returns the corresponding type. I wish to make this function **return `any` if we don't pass a parameter**.

```
const person = useData("person");  // const person: Person
const animal = useData("animal");  // const animal: Animal
const notKnown = useData();   // const notKnown: any
```

I've tried the following implementation:

```
function useData<T extends keyof DataCategory>(category?: T) {
  const data: any = getData();
  return data as T extends undefined ? any : DataCategory[T];
}

const animal = useData("animal");
//    ^ const animal: Animal

const notKnown = useData();
//    ^ const notKnown: Person | Animal
// However, I want the above to be `const notKnown: any`
```

That doesn't work because `useData()` returned `Person | Animal` instead of `any`. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default TS will use the constraint as the type for a type argument it can't infer (and in this case there is no location to infer `T` from). You could change this by using `any` as the default:

```
function useData<T extends keyof DataCategory = any>(category?: T) {
  const data: any = getData();
  return data as T extends undefined ? any : DataCategory[T];
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAChBOBnA9gOygXigbyqghgLYQBcUiw8AlqgOYDcU+tpeAroQEYJQC+9AKFCQoAQVRVC+ADaYc5SAGMqERGQrU6fQQID0AKn1QBUIwBUAFlURQawBADN8i6BWTxVTabIDWqZADu6MicAFYQisBQwp4ewGzwqBAAJlCcIFAABizAACL4wPgAFACUmQB0JkYAkgDkhOTA7jS0tlH4Nvjodo7O0DQUEPipyA5ZcEhoUAA+YhJS0plpEfhsiNDVVXgQKdHIje7QwBbQAESKyMkQp1CjTFB+gegxUEUQ5bTlWaeQk6inSwc7nGCBQqCWMRKlVMugEPXgThcUHyhQAwgUILR3BlsCYoL8wWQJmDBFAmPMZGRxJIZIJeAI9IYoAB5BJQZIFfDkZAJJH6WEXVAUKA5FH4ImgqazakLGbkjJYUqYAB8ODxcQS6Gw-DJul0UAAsshFD5dgA3GRsCACfgMhxsVCRKhTNYQMUAHjMUAgAA97KhkjZTSA7mL0fYsfAFfLlUVFBjIyAAPxkMwlNVkwXCjmFMhdaOizmlUlQDWJdmcpg2L2+-2BqAOq4OGi7JPyqBkMMJ7EAbTMAF06Qys+0KbIsK6xUVTl0adJTiVBHqyWSAHpQEfkudUsfDtDC-zAADS-iCcknRcXen1K-Xm8PJ6eEr+cplMmvUAAEoEIGaEAAaKBqigAIuiiY5oHwThkD-PZliye9kGPU9UDzVAQEyIA)

You can also use overloads as Michael Rose points out in his answer and they might be easier for future readers to understand.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to trying to use generics would be to just overload your `useData` function and specify the category:

```js
function useData(category: "animal"): Animal;
function useData(category: "person"): Person;
function useData(): any;
function useData(category?: string): any {
  return getData();
}

const animal = useData("animal");
//    ^ const animal: Animal

const notKnown = useData();
//    ^ const notKnown: any
```